# Listview's Scroll position in blackberry 10 Native

Tags: listview, qml, blackberry-10

I am Loading 10 Data from server into list-view at a moment, and when user reaches to 10th record it will load more data into list-view, so i have done with this functionality,

So, now the problem is when i scroll down to get more data it loads the data but list-view set it's position to 0, so again user have to scroll to see 11 number data same thing happens for other if again i load more data, means now i have 30 data in list-view, so again i have to start from 0 to check what is data 21.

So what i want to do is when user reaches end position and loads more data i don't want list-view to start from it's 0 position instead of this i want it to set as it is.

So below is my code.

```
ListView {
           id: lstPromotionListOnline
           horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
           attachedObjects: [
                               ListScrollStateHandler {
                               onScrollingChanged: {
                               if (atEnd && scrolling == false) {
                                            if (Global.CurrentPageofList_Promotion == 1) {
                                                Global.CurrentPageofList_Promotion ++;
                                            }
                                            if (connInfo.isConnected()) {
                                                getPagewisePromotionList(Global.CurrentPageofList_Promotion);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
```

So, in above code i am checking whether list-view is reached to it's end position or not, and if it is at it's last position then it will load more data and call web-service if internet is connected.

So how can i achieve this things. I already have tried **scrollToPosition** option but it only provides Beginning and End option which does not fulfill my requirement.

Also i have tried **stickToEdgePolicy** but this also does not fulfill my requirement, So please guide me to solve this problem. Your any help would be appreciated...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i found the perfect solutions for List scroll position.
Please check it out.

```
var index = (Your Variable Name)*10 (Position where you want to move. E.g. 10th position);
(ListViewName).scrollToItem([ index ], ScrollAnimation.None);
```

Hope this will help you.
cheers,

Answer (score 0):

There is a page in the API documentation that addresses this issue: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/data_access/data_manager.html

I suggest you give that a read and see if it doesn't answer your questions.

Comment: @Richards, First of all thank you for your response. Yeah i have read that document, but i didn't understand it properly that how can i move ahead, it will be great if you can provide me any working example.